# Checking two fields for entering characters

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have two fields and a button. Task: the button is inactive until characters are entered in both fields. If at least one field is empty - the button is inactive.

Field id: «zipcode-from» and «zipcode-to»

I have the following code:

```php
jQuery('input#zipcode-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
jQuery('input#zipcode-from').keyup(function(){
    if (jQuery('input#zipcode-from').val() == "") {
        jQuery('input#zipcode-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(':input#zipcode-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

It works for the first field. But how to check both fields? Tried &&, but I can not make this function true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use css syntax to attach the keyup to both fields, then check if one of the fields is empty (you should use OR here). Something like this:

```
jQuery('input#zipcode-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
jQuery('input#zipcode-from, input#zipcode-to').keyup(function(){
if ((jQuery('input#zipcode-from').val() == "")||(jQuery('input#zipcode-to').val() == "")) {
    jQuery('input#zipcode-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
{
    jQuery(':input#zipcode-button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
})
```

Comment: Use `prop('disabled', true)` and `prop('disabled', false)` instead of `attr` and `removeAttr`. See [the documentation (under "Attributes vs. Properties")](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version without the input fields and not using the **jQuery** selector. You don't need to check the value against an empty string but I can understand if you want to for readability purposes. You can use `!$('#zipcode-from').val()` to check if the value is empty.

The if statement is now contained in a [conditional statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5qhkfmdn/1/)

```js
$('#zipcode-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#zipcode-from, #zipcode-to').keyup(function() {
  (!$('#zipcode-from').val() || !$('#zipcode-to').val()) ? $('#zipcode-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled') : $('#zipcode-button').removeAttr('disabled');
})
```